# J function is not working

Tags: math, j

I am a complete beginner to J. My first attempt at writing a function is something like the totient function. It takes an array, assumed to be i.num for some number, num. And then computes the number of elements coprime to the tally of the array.

If I do it manually like this:

```
numbers =: i.7 
#(1=( #numbers)+./numbers)#numbers
```

it works. The result is 6.

So I want to turn this into a general function.

```
Tot =: monad :'(1=( #x)+./x)#x'
Tot i.11
```

This fails and I get a value error for x. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monad's variable should be `y`, not `x`:

```
Tot =: monad :'(1=( #y)+./y)#y'
```

`x` is the left argument of a dyad.

Comment: Oh. I assumed they were interchangeable.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit "strange" that `y` and not `x` is the default "variable". Maybe for historical reasons. [Point 5 here](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm) may shed some light on argument names :)

Comment: In previous versions of J, `y` and `x` were `y.` and `x.`, reserved "primitives" for arguments (along with other ones representing verbs passed as arguments).

Comment: It's only strange until you think of syntax which is `x v y` and as monad takes argument on its right, thus it would be `y` argument